# How to add dynamic partition in Oracle based on Month & Year

Tags: oracle, dynamic, partition

I have a requirement to store an year of data in an ORACLE table (which is truncate & load), so we want to partition the table basis on year and month (like Aug-22, Sep-22 ...) and then can truncate only latest 2 months in every load.
Looking out for option to implement the dynamic partition addition in Oracle table.

Comment: Use `partition by range(date_col) interval( interval '1' month)`. https://dbfiddle.uk/kdZU1U0s

Comment: Thanks @astentx can we generate the system partitions created with a specific name (not asking the renaming thing), while the partitions are created it is created with something like P_202209 , P_202210 and likewise

Comment: There's no way to influence the naming of system-generated objects. For maintenance purposes you may use `partition for (value)` syntax as an alternative for explicit name. Or filter by `high_value` in `dba_tab_partitions` keeping in mind that it is of `long` type.